# compositions of $n$ with $k$ odd parts where all $k$ parts are odd

Tags: combinatorics

Here's what i've done so far:

$S = N^k$ where $N = \{1,3,5,7,9,\ldots\}$ and $N^k = N \times N \times N\times\cdots$ $k$ times

$$\Phi_S(x) = \Phi_{}N_\text{odd}^k(x)$$
$$\Phi_S(x) = (x + x^3 + x^5 + x^7 +\cdots)^k = \left(\frac x{1-x^2}\right)^k$$

So to find the coefficient of $x^n$
$$[x^n]\left(\frac x{1-x^2}\right)^k = [x^{n-k}](1-x^2)^{-k}$$

And I don't know how to simplify this any further. did i do something wrong in my steps?

Comment: You can use the general binomial theorem to find the coefficient of $x^{2j}$ in the power series expansion of $(1-x^2)^{-k}$. One might instead decide to use Stars and Bars to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The number of compositions of $n$ with $k$ odd parts equals the number of compositions of $n-k$ with $k$ even (possibly zero) parts (because one can start attributing a unit to each part), which equals the number of compositions of $\frac{n-k}2$ with $k$ (possibly zero) parts. This number is$~0$ unless $m=\frac{n-k}2$ is integer, in which case it is $m+k-1\choose m$ (among $m+k-1$ symbols choose $m$ to be units, the remaining $k-1$ become $+~$signs).

Or you could equate the coefficient expression in the question (setting $y=x^2$) to $[y^\frac{n-k}2](1-y)^{-k}$ which, using again $m=\frac{n-k}2$, equals $(-1)^m\binom{-k}m=\binom{k+m-1}m$. The same argument, worded differently.